# @mysqli_select_db -- access denied

Tags: php, mysql, database, function

I want to use `@mysqli_select_db()` to switch between two databases.

Both databases have the exact same user, but when I run this function, I get an `access denied` error.

What is happening?

**Update:** Problem solved. I wrote my database name incorrectly in `@mysqli_select_db()`. Thanks for the help anyways.

Comment: You are sure that you entered the right mysql details (login and database?

Comment: @jordi12100 Yes the first connection works, but switching databases doesn't work.

Comment: Have you tried accessing 2nd database (the one you're trying to switch to) first?

Comment: Yes, I can connect fine, but when I switch to the other database (vice versa), same problem.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Problem solved. I wrote my database name incorrectly in `@mysqli_select_db()`.

Answer (score 2):

`access denied` indicates that user you are using to connect to the database server simply is not allowed to the database you want to switch to. use `GRANT` to extends user's privileges.

Comment: I added the same user to both databases?

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by `added` and how you did it. `access denied` is quite self explanatory. Maybe try using mysql console and log in to that db with login/pass of that user to see if it works. Mind, that beside l/p, check if you correctly granted host for that user to said databse.

Answer (score 0):

Please look at this [list](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/access-denied.html) from MySQL. There can be multiple reasons for this particular error message.

Comment: That didn't really help. I can connect fine, it's just when I switch databases it's a problem.